# ons-lazy-repeat　アイテムの高さを自動にできないのでしょうか？

Tags: onsen-ui

表示するデータ量がアイテムごとに違う場合、アイテムの高さを自動にできないでしょうか？

```
ons.bootstrap();

var dataList = new Array();

$.getJSON("test.json", function(data){

    dataList = data;

});

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {  

  $scope.MyDelegate = {
    configureItemScope : function(index, itemScope) {
        itemScope.item = {
          title: dataList[index].title,
          description: dataList[index].description
        };
    },
    calculateItemHeight : function(index) {
      return 45;//アイテムの高さ
    },
    countItems : function() {
      return 10000000;
    },
    destroyItemScope: function(index, scope) {
    }
  };
}]);
```